# Request Location Swift iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get my app to request the user to allow location services when using the app,

I have imported the following in my `ViewController.swift`

```
import CoreData
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
```

and also have the following code in my `ViewController.swift`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined {
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
```

in addition after doing a bunch of research I found that I had to add the following to my `info.plist`

```
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>AppName needs to use your location to help you find other blah blah blah near you</string>
```

Despite taking these steps when running the app in the simulator I don't get a prompt requesting access when using the app

Comment: That key is outdated. It should be NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

Comment: I just attempted updating the info.plist and running again but still no notification

Comment: Are you sure the current status is .NotDetermined by the way? Try add in a print statement and tell us if it printed

Comment: Correction: I decided to erase the whole Key name and retype it just as you described before and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert below `key` in your `Info.plist`

`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`

Comment: It is already there in my info.plist file. but still not working